# Java Thread giving strange error?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

Sorry about the vague description, i didn't know how to explain it.

I'm creating a thread within my Android/Java app, the code is simple enough but it keeps giving off a strange error?

```
final Thread buttonPress = new Thread(){ //X
    try {
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1_down);
        wait(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
    }
}; //XX
```

Besides where i marked /X i get the error message

"Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement"

And at the end of thread, besides the "//XX" i get the error message,

"Syntax error on token "}", delete this token"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want something like

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // your try-catch-finally block goes here
    }
}
```

i.e. your missing a method declaration in your anonymous Thread class.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do it is

```
 new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}}).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed your `run()` method. So you change your code as,

```
final Thread buttonPress = new Thread() { // X
            public void run() {
                try {
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1_down);
                    wait(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    findViewById(R.id.button1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button1);
                }
            }
        }; // XX
```

Answer (score 0):

You're subclassing `Thread` (via `Thread(){}`) but you appear to need a defined method within that to override. Your try/catch exists outside any method as it stands and I suspect you need to override the `run()` method. See [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run%28%29) for more info.